# pandas_datareader in Anaconda Prompt

Tags: python-3.x, pandas-datareader

hoping to get some help with regards to pandas_datareader module.
I have installed the package like this from the command prompt

```
conda install -c anaconda pandas-datareader
```

It installed perfectly and when I go directly to python in the command prompt and type the following

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
```

it executes with success and I can use the module from there.

I am now trying to use it to within a script in Atom text editor and when I go to run the script in the Anaconda Prompt I get a ModuleNotFoundError which tells me the package doesn't exist, despite the fact that it works fine in the standard command prompt.

Is there something additional I have to install in order to get it to run in the Anaconda prompt? I am quite confused.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and please forgive me if the answer is glaringly obvious but I couldn't find any searches matching.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[These Github users](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/180) experienced the same issue you are now. The problem is that Anaconda Prompt isn't starting knowing where the Anaconda packages are. The instructions to fix it are in that thread, or you just use the command line. There is no discernible difference.